# Allowing Wireless Clients Access To Your Network

Tags: wireless-networking, security, airport

Allowing Wireless Clients Access To Your Network

I have company coming over and I'd like to offer my Wi-Fi connection Using my Airport Express without giving them my network password.  I have an iMac, they have Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you have an AirPort Express. The AirPort Extremes and Time Capsules since 2008 (all the "simultaneous dual-band" models) have supported a "Guest Network" feature that does exactly what you want. But the AirPort Express doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just create a new password before they come over.  Give them the easy peasy one, and change it back when they leave?